# Quarkus: Transaction-Listener

Tags: transactions, listener, quarkus

Is there a way to register a transaction-listener so I can activate a filter on Hibernate-Session when a transaction starts?

I managed to develop a producer for `EntityManager` for the same purpose, but this does not seem to work if a new transaction is started in the same request by `@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`, because `EntityManager` is reused, but filters are cleared.

One solution seems to be a Hibernate-Interceptor, but I couldn't figure out how to register such an interceptor in Quarkus.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a Quarkus-guy, I managed to find a solution:

Set the scope of the `EntityManager`-producer from `@RequestScoped` to `@TransactionScoped`, so the producer is called every time a transaction starts.

For completeness: If you really need to listen to the transaction-start, something along `@Observes @Initialized(TransactionScoped.class)` might do the trick.